# Number of views on question getting updated on refresh; just a coincidence?

Tags: discussion, views

I'm just asking this here out of mere curiosity.

I've noted that once I click on my questions list and go to a question page, if I hit refresh, the number of views count almost always goes up by 1. I mean try it out yourself if you want.

- Go to your questions.
- Click on any random question.
- Note the number of views.
- Hit refresh.

And voila! (I mean most of the time. Mostly only for your first attempt. Not always okay?)

I know this all sounds a bit too paranoid.

Is there any logical reason to this? Or is it just that someone has actually "timed" their view in sync with mine for that particular question? Anyone with me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not a coincidence. **Your view** was counted *after* the page was built, so you need to refresh again to see that the counter has indeed gone up.

Views are tracked per IP address per rolling time window. If you come back to the question in, say, 15 minutes you'll see the counter go up by 1 again.

Comment: Hmm.. Let me do the math.. (9918*15) minutes till I get a Famous Question badge then!

Comment: @shyam: the 15 minutes is an estimate, I don't know the actual size of the window. But yes, it'll take you a while to self-award a Famous Question badge. :-P