# Is there a way to see the logged-in views count for a post?

Tags: support, views

Today I landed the [properties should not be accessed directly issue with woocommerce3.0 checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279193/getting-issue-with-woocommerce3-0-checkout-in-wordpress).

**Update** : Now above question is edited. This is the [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43279193/1) when writing this post.

It has only 1 down votes.

It has almost 2000 views. But I think it should be edited, closed or it should received more down votes since question is not clear(at least it is really hard to read the question).

So I thought that most views are from non-logged-in users. So I have a curiosity to see how many logged-in users have read it?

Comment: No, there's only one kind of view count recorded and that's for everybody.

Comment: It is a unique views per IP-address per 15 minutes. So if you re-visit the question again in 15 minutes it will increase viewaccount again

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63104/does-viewing-your-own-question-add-to-its-view-count/63108#63108

Comment: Just FYI: I edited the question into shape

Answer (score 14):

Views are counted [by IP during a time window](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275046/number-of-views-on-question-getting-updated-on-refresh-just-a-coincidence), no difference is made for logged in and anonymous users.

But even if **that** was taken into account when counting views, it wouldn't be enough to satisfy your underlying question, since *"logged in views"* are not synonymous of *"views capable of casting a vote"*.

You would need to consider:

- Users with less than 125 rep
- Repeated visits by the same user (which can't cast repeat votes)
- Visits by the author of the post
- Visits by users who changed their mind about their previous vote

And probably some other cases I didn't think of.

All in all, I think we have to make do with the simplistic "view" concept we have now, which is sufficient for most if not all use cases.

Comment: If you remove an up/down vote (e.g. after an edit, or before the 5 minute window expires), that does *not* prevent you from voting once you do make up your mind.  It's only for comments where removing an upvote locks you out of any further voting on it.